# Cannot mySQL share a foreign key between tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I get error 1005 when inserting my tables. There's multiple tables referencing to the tables in my design made up in mySQL workbench, but doesn't this work? - a shared foreign contraint among several tables?

Table one is called `languages`. It has a id column for each language in the database. Then we have `productDescription` that has a language column which of course is referenced into the `languages` table.

Is this the reason of why i am getting Error 1005?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:** I have verified that all referenced keys have the same datatype which is TINYINT NOT NULL UNSIGNED.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579/mysql-error-1005-when-adding-tables

Comment: Instead of a natural-language description of your table structure, DDL would make it easier to understand your structure and maybe see your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key names must be unique over the database. This could be it.