# Error 1005 when adding a foreign key constraint on mysql table

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I have a problem when upgrading a django and mysql app with south.

I've tried to make a sql-based upgrade with the code generated by the django sqlall command and I have a similar problem.

Here is the sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE `programmations_basissupport` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `value` numeric(6, 0) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE `programmations_concert` ADD `basis_support_id` integer AFTER program_status_id;

ALTER TABLE `programmations_concert` ADD CONSTRAINT `basis_support_id_refs_id_1e4ed8d7` FOREIGN KEY (`basis_support_id`) REFERENCES `programmations_basissupport` (`id`);
```

An error is raised when adding the FK constraint:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'apidev_mnl.#sql-106e_632b00a' (errno: 150)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Update: DEFAULT values where missing but even if I add the default='' in the django model, the creation of foreign keys fails.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check out this post — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579/mysql-error-1005-when-adding-tables

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about the type mismatch but both are integer(11). The SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS returns an error 'Access denied: you need the PROCESS privilege for this operation'

Comment: You need to run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS as a more privileged account, such as the root mysql user, or else grant the PROCESS privilege to the account you are using.

Comment: my host provider don't give access to this command. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem thanks to a workaround. The alter works ok on my dev machine while it fails on the host. I didn't find the reason but I succeed to make it working by exporting, migrating on my dev machine and  reimporting.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to add a constraint with a symbol/name that already exists.

```
ALTER TABLE `programmations_concert` ADD CONSTRAINT `basis_support_id_refs_id_1e4ed8d7` FOREIGN KEY (`basis_support_id`) REFERENCES `programmations_basissupport` (`id`);
```

can be changed to:

```
ALTER TABLE `programmations_concert` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`basis_support_id`) REFERENCES `programmations_basissupport` (`id`);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This pb is far away now thanks to the workaround i've proposed. I'll check your proposal if the pb pops up again. Best

Answer (score 2):

There was the same problem. 
And finally i find that in referenced table field was "unsigned" but in referencing table - Not unsigned.