# Can't import SQL into PHPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a pre made site for someone .. I'm having some troubles importing some SQL into the DB.

The SQL is right here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12992586/spca2012.sql

The database I've got selected is: wwwspcabm

and I'm trying to import a SQL file that was given to me, and I'm getting this errorError
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `adminUsers` (

 `userId` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `userFirst` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `userLast` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `userEmail` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
 `userPassword` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `userLevel` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `firstLogin` VARCHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `userId` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =7;

MySQL said: 

#1005 -
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are numourous examples on this site of this error <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579/mysql-error-1005-when-adding-tables>

Comment: I've been looking at all of those, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: There are no foreign keys in this sql ...

Comment: I also don't have admin access on the server so I can't see what the status of the engine is..

Comment: I ran this as root and it created it so the chances are the user you are using to create the table doesnt have sufficient privelages for that database? I would talk to your network admin or whoever does have access. Or... you could try removing the last line and seeing if that is what is causing the error.

Comment: I tried removing the last line, no dice .. it could be that I don't have privelages .. I'll check with the network admin

Answer (score 0):

use DB_College; //Your database name
SELECT * FROM TBL_Students; //Run your query.

All I did was running use statement before run my queries. Worked for me.